# use batch file to parse rows in csv file

Tags: csv, parsing, batch-file, command-line, cmd

Update:

I would like to parse a csv file and work with the information. I do not know the number of elements in the line prior to opening the file. I do not know the number of rows. I want to first parse the header, so I can then know which token to use to parse the rows. I wish to get the results in a matrix form, so it is easy to work with.

I would also like to create a csv to export later my results.

Here would be an example of a csv I would like to parse (limited to 3 rows, 10 columns).

```
"","rim_no","account_no","observation_date","observation_month","start_date","maturity_date","days_past_due","rate","spread"
"1",2517,1000008332,20160831,201608,NA,NA,0,17,0
"2",2517,1000008332,20160930,201609,NA,NA,0,17,0
```

I do not know in advance the number of rows and columns. I also do not know the ordering of the columns. Lets say I would like to work withe the account number, the observation month and the rate, first I want to parse the header to get the positions 3,5,9 so I can use them as tokens when parsing the other rows to get the information

I managed to do half the stuff I want to, here is the code I wrote (for now, I  just read and write, later I will keep only the variables I am interested in and do additional computations):

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::Adress of the input and output files

GOTO InFile

:FalseIN 
ECHO You need to enter a valid location for the source file. 
GOTO InFile

:InFile
ECHO Please enter the location of your file in like C:\XXXX\YYYY\ZZZZ\example.csv
SET _fileIn
SET /P _fileIn=Type input: %=%
IF NOT EXIST "%_fileIn%" GOTO FalseIn
ECHO The selected input file to work with is %_fileIn%

:OutFile
ECHO Please enter the name of your output like C:\XXXX\YYYY\ZZZZ\output.csv
SET _fileOut
SET /P _fileOut=Type input: %=%
IF NOT EXIST "%_fileOut%" set "_fileOut=C:\XXXX\YYYY\ZZZZ\Output.csv"
ECHO.>"%_fileOut%"
ECHO The selected output file to work with is %_fileOut%

ECHO stop 1   
@PAUSE

SET _ligne=0
SET _colonne=0

CALL :ParseHeader "%_fileIn%"

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

GOTO :eof
::Parse input file header, first element
:ParseHeader
SET /a _countParse+=1
SET _list=%1
SET _list=%_list:"=%
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=, " %%a IN ('TYPE "%_list%"') DO (
    set _matrice[%_ligne%][%_colonne%]=%%a
    set /a _colonne+=1
    if not "%%b"=="" call :ParseHeaderBis "%%b"
)

GOTO :eof

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

GOTO :eof  
::Parse input file header, from second element onward
:ParseHeaderBis
SET /a _countParseBis+=1
SET _list=%1
SET _list=%_list:"=%
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=, " %%a IN ("%_list%") DO (
    set _matrice[%_ligne%][%_colonne%]=%%a
    if not "%%b"=="" set /a _colonne+=1
    if not "%%b"=="" if %_ligne% equ 0 call :ParseHeaderBis "%%b"
    if "%%b"=="" set /a _ligne+=1
)

@PAUSE

IF %_ligne% gtr 0 GOTO :EchoHeader 

GOTO :eof

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:EchoHeader
FOR /L %%H IN (0,1,%_colonne%) DO (
    echo|set /p=!_matrice[0][%%H]!>>%_fileOut%
    if not %%H equ %_colonne% echo|set /p=,>>%_fileOut%
    if %%H equ %_colonne% echo.>>%_fileOut%
)

@PAUSE

CALL :Next 

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

GOTO :eof
::Parse input file data, from second row onward, get lines
:Next
SET /a _countNext+=1
SET /a _ligneAct=%_ligne%
SET _colonne=0
FOR /F "skip=%_ligne% tokens=* delims=" %%a IN ('type "%_fileIn%"') DO (
    if not "%%a"=="" call :NextBis "%%a"
    if "%%a"=="" goto :eof
)

GOTO :eof

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

GOTO :eof
::Parse the lines from the input file
:NextBis
SET /a _countNextBis+=1
SET _list=%1
SET _list=%_list:"=%
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=, " %%a IN ("%_list%") DO (
    set _matrice[%_ligne%][%_colonne%]=%%a
    if not "%%b"==""  set /a _colonne+=1
    if not "%%b"==""  if %_ligne% equ %_ligneAct%  call :NextBis "%%b"
    if "%%b"==""  set /a _ligne+=1 
)

IF %_ligne% gtr %_ligneAct% GOTO :EchoData 

GOTO :eof

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:EchoData
SET _var=""
FOR /L %%H IN (0,1,%_colonne%) DO (
    if %%H equ 0 set _var=!_matrice[%_ligneAct%][%%H]!
    set _help=!_var!
    if %%H gtr 0 set _var=!_help!, !_matrice[%_ligneAct%][%%H]!
    echo !_var!
    if %%H equ %_colonne% echo !_var!>>%_fileOut%
    ::echo|set /p=!_matrice[%_ligneAct%][%%H]!>>%_fileOut%
    ::if not %%H equ %_colonne% echo|set /p=,>>%_fileOut%
    ::if %%H equ %_colonne% echo.>>%_fileOut%
)

@PAUSE

CALL :Next

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:eof 
@PAUSE
```

ButI still do have two problems:

- I was originally exporting everything the same way I do in
  :EchoHeader, but this is very slow, so I decided to first concatenate
  elements and outsheet the whole row (see :EchoData). The thing is
  that I get an error and cannot export; I do not get why. When I echo
  !_var! and uncomment the last three lines of my for loop in
  :EchoData, I can see that _var is what I want but when commented, it
  just bugs;
- the next/next bis loops are running even when there is nothing
  left to read, I thought my goto :eof would avoid this, but I
  apparently missed something, I could not find what for now.

Any help will be much appreciated.

ps: I do not think my code is optimal, any idea to improve the running time is also appreciated :)

Comment: What exactly do you have trouble with? How does the input CSV file look like?

Comment: Thanks, I forgot it, it is now added

Comment: What is the `%=%` suffix for? And please provide also a sample output file and the related user input. By the way, the line `IF NOT DEFINED "%_fileOut%" set "_fileOut=con"` should actually read `IF NOT DEFINED _fileOut set "_fileOut=con"` (supposing you want to check whether the variable is empty)...

Comment: This is for the user input, so he can fill the data file address

Comment: I kept IF NOT DEFINED "%_fileOut%" set as this is working. Shouldn't I refer to _fileOut this way with %%?

Comment: You want to check whether variable `_fileOut` is defined? then you have to use `if not defined _fileOut`; otherwise, the *content* of the variable, say `test.txt`, together with the enclosing `""`, is taken as a literal variable name `"test.txt"`, which does (most probably) not exist; however, if you want to check whether the variable value points to a file/dir. that does not exist, you need to use `if not exist "%_fileOut%"` instead...

Comment: Thanks. I want to check if the file at the address given by the user has been created, and otherwise create an empty one for my results. I correct it to not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Subroutines/functions are a wonderful thing to structure the code, but:

- you've to take care that program flows not inadvertently into them. Insert a `goto :eof` in front.
- at the end of the sub/function also insert a `goto :eof` to return control to the caller.
- don't use label's inside code blocks, unless you know what you do. Use REMs instead
- to read the first line of a file simply use `set /P "header="<infile.txt`
- you seem to recursively call ParseHeader with different argument types, once a file name and then the remainder of the header (%%b)
- to see intermediate results of your 2-dimensional `_matrice` issue a `set _matrice` before pausing, to see whats inside.

This is not really an answer, but to much to put into comments.

- you could use vbs/PowerShell functions with a file picker instead of error prone manual user input.
- to  help other help you, you should show a typical csv you want to examine and what result you expect (aligned columns for example)

Comment: Thanks:
- added goto :eof before & after, though I am not sure I get why it helps;
- changed :: to rem. Again, in what way it helps? I & the machine still see and interpret as a comment;
- asking user about the address of the file is that address and name are unknown. Couldn't come with a better way of doing it;
- recursively parse, as the number of columns is unknown .The idea is to read the first element (if exists) and test for end of line, if not iterate with the rest of the line, until end of line.